# Почему при отправке сообщений в Кафке, если не правильно написан топик которого не существует то сообщения все равно уходят и нет ошибки?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Почему при отправке сообщений в Кафке, если не правильно написан топик которого не существует то сообщения все равно уходят и нет ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Kafka по умолчанию создает тему, если она не существует.

Чтобы заставить Kafka проверять, существует ли тема, перед тем, как создавать поток, можно настроить соответствующую конфигурацию в настройках Kafka Broker.
За это отвечает конфигурация `auto.create.topics.enable`, и по умолчанию она `= true`. Установка значения `false` должна привести к тому, что если тема не существует, Kafka выдаст ошибку, а не автоматически создаст новую тему.

Дополнительную информацию смотрите в [документации](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs).